# Compiler warning I don't understand - possible uninitialised QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, warnings

I've got what I think is a straightforward bit of code - I want to add 3 strings to a QStringList.  Here's my code:

```
baseName = "qwerty";
QStringList *newBOMList;

for (auto ii = 0; ii <= 2; ii++)
{
    if (ii == 0) {
      newBOMList->append(baseName);
    }else
    if (ii == 1) {
      newBOMList->append("A");
    }else
    if (ii == 2) {
      newBOMList->append(baseName + " description");
    }
}
```

I get a compiler warning on the first append line:

'newBOMList' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
               newBOMList->append(baseName);

but not either of the other two.

This bit of code is in a method of a class.

I do like to at least understand the warnings if not get rid of them in my projects, but I don't really understand why this one occurs.

Any clues, please?

Also, is this the best way to add 3 strings to a QStringList?

Oh - I'm using qt-creator on a linux box - if that makes any difference.

Comment: You forgot to allocate memory for the pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a pointer to a QStringList, but never actually created the object, so the pointer is not initialised.

```
QStringList *newBOMList; //pointer to nowhere, results in error/warning on use
QStringList *newBOMList = new QStringList(); //now you have an actual instance, remember to clear it up with "delete newBOMList "
QStringList newBOMList; //stack/local instance, no need to deallocate
```

If you need a dynamically allocated one, Id strongly advise looking into `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, and similar to manage the memory for you. They take care of deallocating the memory that was allocated without an explicit `delete p`.

e.g. editing your origenal code, these would be options:

```
//local/auto allocated
baseName = "qwerty";
QStringList localBOMList;

for (auto ii = 0; ii <= 2; ii++)
{
    if (ii == 0) {
      localBOMList.append(baseName);
    }else
    if (ii == 1) {
      localBOMList.append("A");
    }else
    if (ii == 2) {
      localBOMList.append(baseName + " description");
    }
}

//dynamically allocated, but will be destroyed as soon as the unique_ptr object is so no need for "delete newBOMList" to prevent a memory leak
baseName = "qwerty";
std::unique_ptr<QStringList> newBOMList(new QStringList());

for (auto ii = 0; ii <= 2; ii++)
{
    if (ii == 0) {
      newBOMList->append(baseName);
    }else
    if (ii == 1) {
      newBOMList->append("A");
    }else
    if (ii == 2) {
      newBOMList->append(baseName + " description");
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks ... it makes perfect sense now.  And thanks for the extra explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`QStringList *newBOMList;` creates a pointer to a `QStringList`.  It does not construct one nor does it allocate any memory for it.  When you go to use it you are invoking **[undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** as you are using an uninitialized pointer.

If you need to crate a pointer to a object use a smart pointer instead of a raw one.  You could use a [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

```
std::unique_ptr<QStringList> newBOMList = std::make_unique<QStringList>();
```